# Spark saveAsTable overwrites data in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using the spark as a kafka stream consumer and I geting a big problem in a production state.

The program running well in the client mode, is appending orc files in a hive table even after restart.

But in the cluster mode the program cleans all files in a directory of this table **after start** and it appends files successful next.

However, metadata of partitions and other created before metas in database (meta mysql) still exists.

Why the directory cleaned in the cluster mode, but in client mode files apending without problem?

```
 dataset.write
  .mode("append")
  .format("orc")
  .option("path", "/path/to_table")
  .partitionBy("col1", "col2")
  .saveAsTable("database.table")
```

I'll be grateful if you any help.